# React Native - Unable to properly set Best Score

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been struggling with this for a while now and it seems like I'm on the right track but I'm getting absolutely no where.

Below is the code:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.interval = null;
      this.state = {
        scored: null,
        score: 0,
        highScore: 0,
        totalScore: 0,
        teamScore: 0
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.createHighScore();
    }

    createHighScore = async () => {
      try {
        const highScore = await AsyncStorage.getItem('highScore');
        const score = await AsyncStorage.getItem('score');
        if (score > highScore) await AsyncStorage.setItem('highScore', score);
        this.setState({ highScore: Number(highScore) });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
```

This is inside the function that deals with the score increments

```
    if (this.state.scored === null) {
        if (this.state.y + radius > NET_Y + NET_HEIGHT / 2 && nextState.y + radius < NET_Y + NET_HEIGHT / 2) {
          if (nextState.x + radius > NET_LEFT_BORDER_X && nextState.x + radius < NET_RIGHT_BORDER_X) {
            nextState.scored = true;
            nextState.score +=1; 
          } else {
            nextState.scored = false;
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to set a highScore with AsyncStorage so it will always store for the user whenever the app is logged back in.  I feel like i'm doing it totally wrong haha.

I apologize if this didn't make enough sense the way I laid it out as I'm still learning JS and RN.

Appreciate it guys

Comment: Which is exactly your question? You're saving the highScore value to AsyncStorage, right? That works?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm getting a NAN.

Comment: Before getting an AsyncStorage value you have to set it. Check if you are saving the value as "10" or 10.

Comment: Hey @JuanCurti, thank's for your help; however I'm a bit confused by what you mean.  Could you possibly a go a bit more in detail or show a snippet of code of what you mean? Sorry for the trouble, cheers!

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer

Comment: Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Before getting an AsyncStorage value you have to set an initial value on it, so that when you read it you can compare both values, score and highscore.

For example:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      //Set default values for score and highScore
      AsyncStorage.setItem('score', 0);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('highScore', 0);

      this.interval = null;
      this.state = {
        scored: null,
        score: 0,
        highScore: 0,
        totalScore: 0,
        teamScore: 0
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.createHighScore();
    }

    createHighScore = async () => {
      try {
        const highScore = await AsyncStorage.getItem('highScore');
        const score = await AsyncStorage.getItem('score');
        //Fix this. Now your highscore should be the score
        if (score > highScore) {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('highScore', score);
          this.setState({ highScore: Number(score) });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Hey Juan, I now I understand what you meant by setting a value to AsyncStorage first, thanks.  However, after running it - I'm getting an exception error:

Exception '-[__NSFCNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ............. was thrown while invoking multiSet on target AsyncLocalStorage with params ( ( ... score, 0 ), 2203 )

cheers

Comment: I got passed it by putting the numbers as strings, yet still no update on the high score

Comment: @krondog Please, read my changes, you were setting the highScore wrong. You can try with alerts to check score and highscore values as well, to debug properly.